# How to rename or delete excel sheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the excel package to create an excel file in flutter.
Is it possible to rename the default sheet "Sheet1" or to delete it? Now I get two sheets "Sheet1" and "test". Thanks!

```
var excel = Excel.createExcel();
var sheet = "test";
excel.updateCell(
    sheet, CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: 0), "NAME",
    fontColorHex: "#FFFFFF", backgroundColorHex: "#000000");
...
var value = await excel.encode();
File(path)
  ..createSync(recursive: true)
  ..writeAsBytesSync(value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find it in the packages example here: https://pub.dev/packages/excel/example

```
excel.delete('Sheet1');
```

Comment: how to use freeze panel functionality in flutter for excel. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
Future<List<int>> exportCliente({List<KeyPair>? headerExcel, List<ClienteSintetico>? clienteSinteticos}) {
var excel = Excel.createExcel();

/*
  * sheetObject.updateCell(cell, value, { CellStyle (Optional)});
  * sheetObject created by calling - // Sheet sheetObject = excel['SheetName'];
  * cell can be identified with Cell Address or by 2D array having row and column Index;
  * Cell Style options are optional
  */

Sheet sheet = excel['Cliente'];
**excel.delete('Sheet1');**

for (KeyPair keyPair in headerExcel!) {
  CellStyle cellStyle = CellStyle(backgroundColorHex: '#9C27B0', fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Arial), fontColorHex: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 10, bold: true);
  cellStyle.underline = Underline.None;
  var cell = sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString(keyPair.key));
  cell.value = keyPair.value;
  cell.cellStyle = cellStyle;
}

for (int i = 0; i < clienteSinteticos!.length; i++) {

  ClienteSintetico clienteSintetico = clienteSinteticos[i];

  List<String> data = [
    clienteSintetico.usuario!.nome!.toString(),
    clienteSintetico.usuario!.email!.toString(),
    clienteSintetico.quantidadePedido!.toString(),
    clienteSintetico.valorTotalPedido!.toString(),
    clienteSintetico.pontosDisponivel!.toString(),
    (clienteSintetico.usuario!.ativo! ? 'Ativo' : 'Inativo'),
  ];
  sheet.appendRow(data);

}

var fileBytes = excel.save(fileName: DateTime.now().toIso8601String() + '_' + 'cliente.xlsx');

return Future<List<int>>.value(fileBytes);
```

}